# How to avoid that pressing the ALT key takes away the focus from my GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a java app with swing in Windows.

The problem is: after pressing (and releasing) the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, the next key press has no effect (there won't be a keyPressed event fired). Only the releasing the next key will be recognized. Pressing and releasing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> after <kbd>ALT</kbd> has no effect at all. The you first have to press another key or click into the component to receive key events from <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> again.

Probably Windows takes the focus away from my GUI component to the title/menu of the frame.
I need <kbd>ALT</kbd>+MouseWheel to move a graphic in my app, if I afterwards wants to zoom the graphic with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+MouseWheel this won't be working. 
So howe to stop <kbd>ALT</kbd> from taking away the focus (but still be able to access a menuItem with e.g. <kbd>ALT+F</kbd>)?

I already tried Component.requestFocus() - but actually my component doesn't lose the focus really.

A simple example which shows the behaviour:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Key perssed: " + arg0.getKeyCode());
}   
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Key released: " + arg0.getKeyCode());
}
}

public class KeyListenerDemo {

public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keytest");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    frame.add(textField);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you consume() the KeyEvents for the ALT key?  I suppose the problem with this would be that it would break the normal functionality of the ALT key in Windows.

Comment: no, I want to keep Windows functionally - to access the menubar. So actually the question is not how to avoid the focus switch - but how to regain the focus.

Comment: kind of solved: Scott, you were right. in my case consume() actually did work. I can use ALT together with the mouse wheel for my functionality, but still access the menu with e.g. ALT+F

Comment: @räph why don't you add an actual answer which shows how you solved the problem, for the benefit of others, it might get lost down here in the comments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case the following worked: KeyEvent.consume()

> Consumes this event so that it will not be processed in the default manner by the source which originated it.

This stops Windows from stealing my focus, but I'm still able to access my menuitems with the keyboard mnemonics with ALT.

Thanks to Scott W for his comment!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, at least not in swing. Every single swing application that I ever used had the same problem. It is one of the main reasons I gave up using Netbeans IDE, although the IDE is generaly very nice. SWT applications don't have that problem.

Comment: I was already afraid to get that answer ;( but isn't there some workaround to gain the key-focus again?