# Zetcode.com Java: Spaceinvaders Player don't move anymore after I shot a bullet

Tags: java

I tried to programm spaceinvaders with the tutorial:
[spaceinvaders](https://zetcode.com/javagames/spaceinvaders/)

Everything is okay so far, but I could'nt find out how to set the focus again
on the player after I did a shot. So the player will not move anymore.
I tried allready a couple of hours and so I know the keyevents are working - until i shoot.
(`System.out.println` - for testing the events are ok)

I can move the player very fast befor I shot, but afterwards no chance.
I can do shots again, but the VK_LEFT` nor the VK_RIGHT will react anymore.

I work with Eclipse Luna and Java build 1.8.0_40, and use the original code,
made me some little PNGs.
I just specified
`Iterator<Alien> it = aliens.iterator();` and
changed: //  `ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(shot));`
to:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(shot);
```

because otherwise I get a NullPointer Exception.

This I tried in the board.class: Workes a litte better, but the player still want move all the time I want.
What bothers me most is, it works some times and without I can find a reason, the player stop and
want move anymore.

```
 private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
          
                 //Original just this code 
               //player.keyReleased(e);
            
            //works better, but still not as expected
            if(ingame)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )
                {
                    player.keyReleased(e);
                    
                }
                 if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ALT) 
                 {
                     player.x += player.dx;
                          if (player.x <= 2) 
                            player.x = 2;
                        if (player.x >= BOARD_WIDTH -2*player.width) 
                            player.x= BOARD_WIDTH - 2*player.width;
                     
                 }
            }
               
        }
```

I hope you can help me.
Nice regards
C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid that pressing the ALT key takes away the focus from my GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868553/how-to-avoid-that-pressing-the-alt-key-takes-away-the-focus-from-my-gui)